# Can't access form data in PHP

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm not a novice, but I'm not an expert either; I'm a keen learner.

Problem (minimalised) - I have a basic form which posts a name to another page which is supposed to receive name and print name. Code of both forms is below.

Form:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, World!";
    echo "
        <form action='CFAcomments.php' method='POST'>
            <table style='width: 50%;' border='0'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for='name'>name: </label></td>
                        <td><input type='Text' name='name' value='anon' /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type='submit' name='send' value='Send' /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    ";
?>
```

Form Process:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello, World 1!";
    echo "<br/>";
    var_dump($_POST);
    $name = $_POST("name");
    echo "Hello $name!";
?>
```

Result:

```
Hello, World 1!
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(11) "anon" ["send"]=> string(4) "Send" }
```

Problem:

Even though var_dump($_POST) shows data being sent, `echo $name` print nothing. Changing `echo $name` to `echo "test"` prints nothing too. The code seems to stop executing at `$name = $_post("name");`. If I remove this line `echo "anything"` works.

I've used PHP and forms for the last two years and never come across this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Array keys are referenced with square brackets, not parentheses.

```
$name = $_POST("name");

// Should be
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not using the right  brackets. It has to be:

```
$_POST['name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the incorrect syntax for $_POST. It should be

```
 <?php
    $name = $_POST["name"]; 
    echo "hello $name !"; 
 ?>
```

You are accessing it like a function instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = $_POST("name");
```

is not the correct way. It should be:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

since $_POST is an array.

Comment: :) Happens to everyone. Please, take time to mark one of the answers as accepted, it helps improve the content quality on the website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

$_POST["name"];

$_POST is an associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

Note the square brackets, because $_POST is an array, not a function.

Answer (score 1):

To access array's element you have to use square brackets. So, it's just replacing

```
$name = $_POST("name");
```

with

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```